# can't chown /usr/local for homebrew in Mac OS X 10.13 High Sierra

Tags: permissions, homebrew

Homebrew needs permissions in /usr/local and since no one else uses my laptop I have always simply done

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)`

but in High Sierra, this gives

`chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`

What is the fix?

Comment: Solved with : sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local/*

Comment: Adding `/*` to the end like so: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` worked for me

Comment: What happened on my machine is I got the "permission denied" error, but when I ls -l it still lists all directories as the new chowner I just assigned, but did not change the actual permissions, so some Homebrew directories still get "permission denied" errors when updating yet the owner is the new owner.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

The problem kept occurring... after digging deeper I found that only uninstalling Homebrew and then re-installing it solved this issue.

Uninstalling will remove all your brew packages, you can save the output of `brew list` in a file first, to have a record of what packages were installed.

Uninstall Homebrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Then re-install it:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: this was the only way to fix my homebrew after "High" Sierra upgrade.

my error was:

`gh4x-mbpr:~ gh4x$ brew link git
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.15.0... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib`

and 

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

didnt help...

Comment: Unbelievable.  Failed the first time, uninstall script failed, second install worked.

Comment: You might like to save the output of `brew list` in a file first, to have a record of what packages were installed.

Comment: None of the other various Mojave homebrew fixes would work on my system. Uninstall/Reinstall worked perfectly.

Comment: Been searching for a solution to chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted for an hour or so. This was the only solution that worked out of many others.

Comment: I think @Reza Farshi is the best. This answer doesn't actually explain what was creating the issue, or how it is fixed.

Comment: Works also with Catalina

Comment: FYI. Uninstalling removes all of your brew packages

Comment: This still works on Big Sur. I was getting bunch of 'permission denied' errors when trying to install a package (azure-cli). brew update, upgrade, doctor, did not help. Uninstalling and reinstalling worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 66):

Unfortunately you can no longer chown `/usr/local` in High Sierra. A workaround is to `sudo mkdir /usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/Frameworks` if they don't exist, and

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

Thanks to ilovezfs for this simple workaround and for the amazing homebrew!

Comment: Still not working. $ brew update
Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable.

Comment: Try uninstall and re-install Homebrew:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459152/cant-chown-usr-local-for-homebrew-in-osx-10-13-high-sierra

Comment: as i commented elsewhere, uninstalling removes ALL your brew packages.

Comment: `$(brew --prefix)` should evaluate to `/usr/local/`, i believe.

Answer (score 55):

You can not change permission for `/usr/local` itself , but you can change the right permission for folders underneath , so this fixed the
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*`

Comment: Get same issue still

Comment: Running on MacOS High Sierra. Worked. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me on: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 12):

I am using **MacBook Pro macOS Catalina 10.15.4**.

I created a `new admin account` but the brew was throwing an error.

Hence, I followed a step from this post, what worked is:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved my day. I'm using Big Sur.

Answer (score 8):

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46459153/4502723) but the problem still persist.
So, I reinstalled *homebrew* without uninstalling previous one. It's working now!
 
(I don't know how)

Comment: I recommend to completely uninstall Homebrew & then install it again.

Comment: Multiple installed did work, I wasn't able to fix it until I uninstalled.

Comment: uninstalling will screw everything up. I have tons of packages installed and will have to go through and install them all over again. Sadly this all worked previously because I HAVE those packages.

Answer (score 6):

I just run this and everything gets taken care on high sierra:

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling [System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html). From the documentation:

> System Integrity Protection can be configured using the csrutil(1) command.
>
> You can check whether System Integrity Protection is currently enabled on your system by running the following command in the Terminal:

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
```

> To enable or disable System Integrity Protection, you must boot to Recovery OS and run the csrutil(1) command from the Terminal.
>
> Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the Command and R keys at startup.
>   Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu.
>   Enter the following command:
>   `$ csrutil enable`
>
> After enabling or disabling System Integrity Protection on a machine, a reboot is required.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is a little like removing the guard from your table saw. It works, and it might be necessary sometimes, but it's safer if you don't have to do it. Setting yourself as the owner of /usr/local to make homebrew work always seemed like a hack anyway.

Comment: This is highly discouraged! It's extremely dangerous unless the user doesn't what he/she is doing.

Comment: @oligofren :D :D :D come on man. Relax, it's not an english `word in context` contest. :D :D Flag to warn user. But alright, you pick up wordings for me then :p :p

Answer (score 2):

if you are using zsh 
because you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
you should add `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
 in .zshrc

then it should work, this problem resolved in my mac by this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also on 10.13 High Sierra. I tried the previous suggestions; nothing worked. Eventually I tried installing the [command-line tools](https://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/) first:

`xcode-select --install`

and then afterwards (re-)ran the brew install command:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

and it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a lock set on the home folder or any folder an install needs access to.

Even if the permissions and ownership are set correctly and you are currently logged in with a correct user/or Root user it will not allow you to make new folders or directories.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the /user/local/Frameworks folder, so this fixed it for me

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks
```

I have OSX High Sierra