# chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted - issue with brew update /usr/local is not writable - MacOS 10.13.1 high sierra

Tags: macos, homebrew, chown

I am unable to do brew update because I can’t chown `/usr/local`:

```
$ brew update
Error: /usr/local is not writable. You should change the ownership
and permissions of /usr/local back to your user account:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

based on this: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/385

I tried these 2 chown command but it didnt work:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted


$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
```

Here is my `/usr/local` listing:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ ls -al
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 23 root wheel 736 Dec 2 15:24 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 9 root wheel 288 Oct 26 00:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 megasap wheel 0 Dec 2 15:11 .com.apple.installer.keep
drwxr-xr-x 16 megasap admin 512 Jan 11 14:08 .git
drwxr-xr-x 5 megasap admin 160 Dec 2 15:24 .github
-rw-r--r-- 1 megasap admin 1112 Aug 11 2016 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 megasap admin 253 Aug 11 2016 .travis.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 megasap admin 291 Aug 11 2016 .yardopts
-rw-r--r-- 1 megasap admin 3161 Aug 11 2016 CODEOFCONDUCT.md
drwxr-xr-x 35 megasap admin 1120 Jan 11 11:35 Cellar
-rw-r--r-- 1 megasap admin 1241 Jan 26 2016 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x 9 megasap admin 288 Dec 2 15:25 Library
-rw-r--r-- 1 megasap admin 5451 Aug 11 2016 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 262 megasap admin 8384 Jan 11 23:09 bin
drwxr-xr-x 11 megasap admin 352 Dec 2 15:25 etc
drwxr-xr-x 57 megasap staff 1824 Dec 2 15:25 include
drwxr-xr-x 102 megasap staff 3264 Dec 2 15:25 lib
drwx------ 4 megasap wheel 128 Dec 2 15:24 libexec
drwxr-xr-x 3 megasap admin 96 Dec 2 15:23 n
drwxr-xr-x 34 megasap admin 1088 Dec 2 15:25 opt
drwxr-xr-x 8 megasap admin 256 Dec 2 15:24 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 16 megasap admin 512 Dec 2 15:25 share
drwxr-xr-x 8 megasap admin 256 Dec 2 15:25 var
```

I'm using macOS 10.13.1 high sierra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't chown /usr/local for homebrew in OSX 10.13 High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459152/cant-chown-usr-local-for-homebrew-in-osx-10-13-high-sierra)

Answer (score 10):

Reinstalling Homebrew worked for me

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Expect to get `Error: The Ruby Homebrew installer is now disabled and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

For more see: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is due to mac's "system integrity configuration". To get around this you need to reboot your machine into recovery mode (restart your machine and hold down ⌘+R) go into Utilities > Terminal and type the command:

```
csrutil disable
reboot
```

And then run your chown command. I guess its recommended to reenable this after changing permissions to re-enable the security.

Full disclosure, I haven't tried this myself - I'll give it a go later today since its a massive PITA. For the record, I'm only attempting to install python3.

[Original information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled)

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, I have to give "Full Disk Access" to the terminal using the below page -

https://macreports.com/terminal-says-operation-not-permitted-on-mac-fix/

Answer (score -3):

uninstall and install Homebrew using https://github.com/Homebrew/install

Comment: It is not necessary to uninstall first, you can just re-run the install