# gcc 7.1 install problem on mac high sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, gcc

I am trying to install gcc 7.1 (http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) on a mac high sierra 10.13.6.

After download gcc compressed file, I run the following command,

```
gunzip gcc-7.1-bin.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf  gcc-7.1-bin.tar -C /.
```

it prompts out the following error

> x usr/local/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usr/localFailed to set file flags

I searched online and this seems a permission issue. I followed the steps in https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228, and tried the two different ways that have been reported successful

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

or create the /usr/local/include directory before running `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` to fix.

None of this work for me. Does anyone has any idea about for my problem? Not sure if this is an easy one.

Comment: I followed the direction in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459152/cant-chown-usr-local-for-homebrew-in-osx-10-13-high-sierra and use sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
After that, just use chmod 777 *

Comment: The above steps fix my previous issue. However, when I run  tar -xvf gcc-7.3-bin.tar -C /.   I got the following error message: usr/local/: Can't update time for usr/local
usr/local/bin/
usr/local/.com.apple.installer.keep: Can't unlink already-existing object

Comment: Previous steps have fixed the problem. The error message seems like just a warning.